# Intsall jekyll in subpath

Tags: github, jekyll

I have [github repository](https://github.com/tencet/tencet.github.io). In folder Blog placed jekyll which work if it is root folder.

I want run `/Blog/index.html` from `/index.html`

```
<a href = "Blog/index.html"> Blog </a>
```

_config.yml

```
# Site settings
title: About the Programing
email: tencet@yandex.com
baseurl: "Blog" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "http://tencet.github.io/" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
github_username:  tencet
source: ./Blog
destination: ./Blog
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Config:source:'Blog'* -> *Github page generate* -> puts result a the root

If you want an independent index at the root an be able to point to **tencet.github.io/blog** :

- create a **blog** repository,
- put your jekyll blog in it, it will then be available at **tencet.github.io/blog**.

Comment: I change `_config.yml => source: Blog`. And Generated github page, but site doesn't work 'The file Blog/css/main.scss` contains syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks I changed `source: ./Blog` in gh-page branch